# Xcode Linker command failed using Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I'm getting the following error when using visual studio to run `flutter run verbose` at the root of my flutter project.

```
[   +1 ms] Error (Xcode): Building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/my_app/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps) built for 'iOS'
           
[        ] Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
           
[   +1 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[        ] Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 50,702ms.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:828:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1383:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:360:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:300:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

I've seen some threads that told me to run it in Xcode, right click the error, and reveal in log, but nothing will pop up. All similar threads I'm seeing are from at least six years ago, and they mostly seem to be linked to updating Xcode. However, I'm working on this project with at team, and the project compiles on their macs with the exact same version of Xcode.

Another note: the basic flutter sample project that is created with `flutter create example_app` will compile completely fine, so I suspect it might be something in the gitignore files, but I've been on this for a few weeks with no luck. Please help, and thank you so much!

Comment: Try opening it in xcode as advised but open the pods file instead and in the minimum ios deployment for each package, set it to at least 12.0. Then close and open the project again, let Xcode finish indexing the project and use the run button on Xcode to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you’re building the app for iOS simulator with precompiled third party library GoogleMaps.framework, the library was built for iOS devices, which is not compatible with simulators.

Try to built the project for iOS device. Or find the GoogleMaps library built for simulators